# Does a higher resolution show more of the world, given the same aspect-ratio?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Does a 16:9 1920x1080 screen show more of the world compared to a 16:9 1600x900?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 5):

No.

A 16:9 resolution will display the same amount of content as another 16:9 resolution.  The difference between the resolutions will be the **detail** of what you see, not how much you see.

Comment: A smaller resolution will have a bigger UI, but UI size can be changed in settings, so that's not much of an issue.

Comment: You could change the new FoV setting to view more of the game world.

Comment: @Chippies you can change it… up to a point. With _very_ high resolutions, even the biggest interface is still kind of small. (and with _extremely_ high resolutions, it's unplayable). HTH.